# Next Js V13 When route is not found, its continues to retry fetching infinitely

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I next Js v13 using the app directory. When route is not found, its continues to retry fetching infinitely. How can you fix that?
Here is a sample [image: infinite refetching]

I have tried adding the error file and seams not to work as well

Comment: Could you provide a code sample, maybe?

Comment: @RyanLe this is from the basic routing example.. see https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/pages-and-layouts

Comment: This is expected behaviour when running the app in development mode. Running the app in production mode (`next build && next start`) should not trigger the re-fetching.